# How to change multi-languages with Spring on project EgovFramework?

Tags: spring-mvc, internationalization

I have a problem with multi-languages with Spring on project EgovFramework.

My problem cannot change language when I request like that http://localhost:8080/common/cop/adb/selectAdbkList.do?language=en_us , it should be changed all the labels and the name of button to english.

Here is my code context-common.xml for call files messages

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
        <property name="paramName" value="language" />
    </bean>
<!-- <bean id="localeResolver" -->
<!-- class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver"
    /> -->
<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="ko_KR" />
</bean>

<bean id="handlerMapping"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="interceptors">
        <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:egovframework/message/com/messages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="fallbackToSystemLocale" value="false" />
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="3" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    <property name="fileEncodings" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>

<!-- <bean id="messageSource" -->
<!-- class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource"> -->
<!-- <property name="basenames"> -->
<!-- <list> -->
<!-- <value>classpath:/egovframework/message/com/message-common -->
<!-- </value> -->
<!-- </list> -->
<!-- </property> -->
<!-- <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" /> -->
<!-- <property name="cacheSeconds"> -->
<!-- <value>60</value> -->
<!-- </property> -->
<!-- </bean> -->

<bean id="placeholderConfig"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <array>
            <value>classpath:/egovframework/egovProps/globals.properties
            </value>
            <value>classpath:/egovframework/rte/fdl/property/messages/properties.properties
            </value>
            <value>classpath:/egovframework/rte/fdl/idgnr/messages/idgnr.properties
            </value>
        </array>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="egovMessageSource" class="egovframework.com.cmm.EgovMessageSource">
    <property name="reloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <ref bean="messageSource" />
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- 실행환경에서 빈 이름 참조(AbstractServiceImpl) -->
<bean id="leaveaTrace" class="egovframework.rte.fdl.cmmn.trace.LeaveaTrace">
    <property name="traceHandlerServices">
        <list>
            <ref bean="egov.traceHandlerService" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="egov.traceHandlerService"
    class="egovframework.rte.fdl.cmmn.trace.manager.DefaultTraceHandleManager">
    <property name="reqExpMatcher">
        <ref bean="egov.antPathMater" />
    </property>
    <property name="patterns">
        <list>
            <value>*</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="handlers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="egov.defaultTraceHandler" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="egov.antPathMater" class="org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher" />

<bean id="egov.defaultTraceHandler"
    class="egovframework.rte.fdl.cmmn.trace.handler.DefaultTraceHandler" />


<!-- MULTIPART RESOLVERS -->
<!-- regular spring resolver -->
<bean id="spring.RegularCommonsMultipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000000" />
    <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="100000000" />
</bean>

<!-- custom multi file resolver -->
<bean id="local.MultiCommonsMultipartResolver" class="egovframework.com.cmm.web.EgovMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000000" />
    <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="100000000" />
</bean>

<!-- choose one from above and alias it to the name Spring expects -->
<!-- alias name="local.MultiCommonsMultipartResolver" alias="multipartResolver" 
    / -->
<alias name="spring.RegularCommonsMultipartResolver" alias="multipartResolver" />

<context:component-scan base-package="egovframework, example">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation"
        expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Service" />
    <context:include-filter type="annotation"
        expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Repository" />
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation"
        expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
</context:component-scan>
```

Here is the classpath of all files messages.

- egovframework.message.com

  - messages_en_US.properties
  - messages_ko_KR.properties

Please Help me, why I cannot change when i request ?language=en_us on browser.....

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know project EgovFramework, but with normal Spring you should have this in your configuration to change the language:

```
 <mvc:interceptors>
   <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor" p:paramName="language" />
 </mvc:interceptors>
```

Then there seams to be an other mistake: You used different casing:
The file is named (correct) `messages_en_US.properties`. But you tryed `?language=en_us`. Try `?language=en_US` instead.